# Youtube embedded videos are not playing on site

Tags: html

I can not figure out why Youtube embedded videos are not playing on a site.

http://dread.dev.hammermedia.ca/portfolio/city-of-airdrie-transit-series/

I've tried clearing the cache on browser, trying another browser, playing with the HTML. I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: Your link does not work. We could better help you with actual code.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Sorry it does work now. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this youtube help email. Apparently there has been an internal error at Youtube for almost a week.

[Youtube Problem Ticket](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/nK7kwlhSBuQ)

I've seen posts that old Object method is working, but not sure there are resources to find old parameters.

I did find this on another youtube help post about a similar down-time issue in 2017

```
<object width="500" height="350"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/THE_VIDEO_ID"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/THE_VIDEO_ID" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="500" height="350"></embed></object>
```